A famous saying or expression to convey "Your highest hopes are old memories to us"
I was wondering if there is a famous saying, an expression (preferably somewhat insulting in tone), to say "Your highest hopes are old memories to us".

If this is from another language, could you include the original proverb in its own language, please?

And do you want a synonym for the entire expression (which I assume, based on your quotation marks), or is a partial alternative sufficient (seeing that currently two out of three answers provide the latter)? Can you [edit] your question to make this and Conrado's requests clear, preferably providing a lucid context, as well?

I assume you mean that what some see as a wild ambition is an everyday occurrence or state to the speaker.

That's old hat.


old hat [phrase]: If you say that something or someone is old hat, you mean that they have existed or been known for a long time, and
they have become uninteresting and boring. [Collins]

It is usually said in a put-down, disabusing way.


(Cambridge Dictionary) stand the test of time If something stands the test of time, it is still popular, strong, etc. after a long time:


Your highest hopes did not stand the test of time.


While this might work, I think the poster is looking for some zinger said in a rather mocking way.


(Dictionary.com) Idioms and Phrases
gone with the wind
Disappeared, gone forever, as in With these unforeseen expenses, our profits are gone with the wind. This phrase became famous as the title of Margaret Mitchell's 1936 novel, which alludes to the Civil War's causing the disappearance of a Southern way of life. It mainly serves as an intensifier of gone.

(ENGLISH MULTI TASKING STAFF MULTIPLE CHOICE QUESTIONS: ...
Mocktime Publication) All laudable objectives of kindling originality and problem solving are trumpeted only in educational seminars and workshops. Ultimately all these are gone with the wind.

As far as we are concerned your highest hopes are gone with the wind.


Taking a cue from Edwin's answer (I didn't quite make out what the question was asking), I propose that old chestnut.
an/that old chestnut
